# Плагин fancybox 3

Tags: yii2, fancybox

Подскажите, пожалуйста, плагин fancybox 3 не открывает такие форматы как docx, rtf.  Появляется ошибка:

[image: Error fancybox 3]

Может есть решение проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FancyBox больше не выпускается. Это написано на [официальном сайте](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос